# My paypal standard integration works (github.com/paypal-examples/docs-examples/tree/main/standard-integration) Need steps to integrate to a new page

Tags: github, paypal

I implemented the example and got the paypal standard integration to work properly, but when I try to transfer the code into my website, it does not work. in displays an error 'cannot Get'

What I did was I transferred the script code from the index.html to my web page, titled webpage.php, and it gave the error.

What I would like is to get the proper integration steps that work in the sample and transfer it to an entirely new page.

Any ideas or feedbacks would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks
Frank

I did do is that I set up the example in my xampp local directory.

I configured with my paypal sandbox credentials

I opened up node.js app and ran it from that local directory.

executed npm i
execute npm start

it was listening on http://localhost:8888/

When I went to that site, it displayed the paypal buttons properly and I tested it with my sandbox accounts and it worked properly.

When I tried to transfer the script form the index.html to my page website.php I was expecting the port http://localhost:8888/ to pick up the paypal requests. All I get when I listen to that port is 'Cannot Get'

Answer (score 0):

localhost (port :8888) is your local computer or the computer of the browser accessing the page, hence the word "local".

You need to actually deploy the backend (in this case, the node.js sample application) to your webserver. Contact your web hosting provider for details, or read its documentation on how to have it host a node.js app. (Alternatively, you could reimplement the sample node.js code in PHP if that is your language environment of choice to be working with; the node code PayPal provides is only an example and any other could potentially be used)

Once your backend is live on your website and has the equivalent 'create' and 'capture' routes listening for connections, change your index.html to make use of them, using relative paths that do not include the protocol http/hostname/domain/port -- just the path.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I have the example running on my local host only. I have tried to maintain the same environment when I transfer the code to a different page, but it does not capture any information. Locally, with the origional example, it works fine. I am using the  the node.js sample application. My intention is to use the code from the sample index.html into a different page, in which I am using a php environment. I was wondering what the steps would be to get it transfered from the index.html to a local webpade.php if possible. Thanks.

Comment: You will need to implement equivalent functionality to the server js file by writing your own PHP code to do all the same things the node example is doing.